# Recalculate Price Filter when using an observer to change prices

Tags: product, layered-navigation, filter

I'm using an observer to change the price of some products for the list view using `setFinalPrice()`.

However, this does not update the price filter in the layered navigation.

Any ideas how I would update this? I've checked documentation and tried searching for similar issues, but haven't found anything.

Answer (score 1):

Did you think about changing the PriceIndexer instead of setting the price on the product? I think this is a better approach.